Скопировать значение строки из таблицы в textarea
При двойном клике на строку - копируется ее значение.


// You can use any function to copy here
function copyToClipboard(textToCopy) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.value = textToCopy;
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  input.remove();
}

function copyLastColumn(tr) {
  copyToClipboard(tr.lastElementChild.innerHTML);
  // alert('copied to clipboard');
}
<tr ondblclick="copyLastColumn(this)">
  <td>какое-то значение</td>
</tr>



Как сделать, чтобы при двойном клике значение строки сразу копировалось в поле textarea с id="replace"

Что-то не видно ваших попыток решения данной задачи. Добавьте их и скажите где именно возникли труудности.

как будто бы:
document.GetElementByID("replace").Value = <твой метод с return-ом скопированного текста>

Можно обернуть в еще одну абстракцию для того, чтобы ты какую-нибудь доп. логику добавил туда если надо.

document.GetElementByID("replace").Value будет undefined потому, что нет Value, есть value.

А если сделать возможность добавления значений через (+=)
То как сделать в этом варианте, чтоб строки шли с новой строки, а не добавлялись слитно к предыдущей?
Из  копируем значения в <textarea id="replace>
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function() {
document.getElementById("replace").value += document.getElementById("result").value;
}, false);

а почему не можешь сделать так, что у тебя внутри контейнера replace  создается при каждой отработке метода новый блок? по типу repalce и в нём id1, id1 или класс replaceitem
